# Is there any way to change textColor of label in SnackBarAction without changing inversePrimary of colorScheme?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

[image]The issue is in Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7). It is by default taking value of inversePrimary from colorScheme, and not getting overridden by either actionTextColor in Theme or textColor in the SnackBarAction widget itself.

```
action: SnackBarAction(
     label: 'Undo',
     onPressed: () {},
     textColor: Colors.red,
),

 snackBarTheme: const SnackBarThemeData(
      actionTextColor: Colors.red,
    ),

inversePrimary: Color(0xFF86D992),
```

In above code textColor is getting the value of inversePrimary insted of themedata or textcolor value.

Comment: man u should add some pics

Comment: @JBJason Checkout the code..  https://github.com/s4nk37/myshop/blob/master/lib/widgets/product_item.dart

Comment: without inversePrimary, does it work accordingly ?

Comment: @JBJason No. It shows white color.

Comment: @JBJason   textColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                                (states) => Colors.red), adding this thing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this worked.

```
snackBarTheme: SnackBarThemeData(
  actionTextColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.red),
),
```

OR

```
textColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.red),
```